How to configure output blob binding with dynamic name in .NET 8 Azure Function?
I've upgraded my Azure Functions project from .NET 6 to .NET 8 and started using dotnet-isolated instead of dotnet. I noticed that all the objects that worked when added to the function signature no longer work. For example,
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("45 0 0 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter, Binder binder, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed with frequency: {myTimer}");
    await csvFileCreater(binder).ConfigureAwait(false);
    log.LogInformation($"FunctionName - completed.");
}

        
private static async Task<string> csvFileCreater(Binder binder)
{
    string csvFileName = CommonUtils.GenerateCSVFileName();
    var attributes = new Attribute[]
    {
        new BlobAttribute($"containerName/{csvFileName}"),
        new StorageAccountAttribute("AzureWebsJobsStorage")
    };
    using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes))
    {
        writer.Write($"ColumnName ");
    }
    return csvFileName;
}

From the example code above, both Binder and ILogger worked correctly in .NET 6.
However, after upgrading to .NET 8, values of Binder and ILogger are no longer injected. I found the workaround for logging and have logging enabled in my project by adding logging to my Program.cs file:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((appBuilder, services) =>
    {
        var config = appBuilder.Configuration;
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSingleton<Binder, Binder>();
        services.AddHttpClient();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

How do I add Binder (or any other object) to my function so I can use output blob binding with a dynamic blob name in .NET 8 Azure Function?

I am also migrating my azure functions to .net with from in-process model to isolated worker model. In one of my azure function I am using Binder to dynamically bind blob. I am also getting null object reference exception. Did you find any solution for that?

So, you want in a Timer Trigger, dynamically construct a Blob name and create a new Blob.

I don't think that Dependency Injection works in the same way with static methods in .NET 8 Azure Functions. I don't know how to make it work with static methods.
Anyways, you need to do number of changes because Isolated Mode is working based on completely different set of NuGet packages.
In-process mode uses these NuGets:

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

Isolated mode uses:

Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker
Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask
etc.


❗ Don't forget to set environment variable:
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
Locally it should be set in local.settings.json. When deployed, it should be set as Environment Variable in the Configuration of the Azure Function Azure Resource.


How to figure the solution out:

Just create a new Azure Function project with .NET 8 Isolated Mode in Visual Studio
Make class and method of the function trigger not static
Add input binding for BlobContainerClient
Upload blob


So, you should define your function in such way:
// IMPORTANT: Class is not `static`
public class Function1
{
    private readonly Binder _binder;

    // Dependency Injection of the `Binder` instance via constructor
    public Function1(Binder binder)
    {
        _binder = binder;
    }

    // IMPORTANT: Class method is not `static`
    [Function("FunctionName")]
    public async Task Run(
         [TimerTrigger("45 0 0 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer,
         // This is how you inject the `DurableTaskClient`
         [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
         // Bind `BlobContainerClient` to the container "containerName"
         [BlobInput("containerName")] BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient,
         // You also need to inject standard `FunctionContext`
         FunctionContext functionContext)
    {
        // Create a logger
        ILogger logger = functionContext.GetLogger("FunctionName");

        // Generate blob name
        var blobName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.csv";
        var blobData = "data";
        
        await blobContainerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobName, BinaryData.FromString(blobData));
    }
}


In my example:

Function is defined as a non-static class
Parameters DurableTaskClient and FunctionContext should be defined
Then logger can be created using executionContext.GetLogger()
Parameter BlobContainerClient should be decorated with an attribute [BlobInput("containerName")] that points to an existing container with name containerName


Links:

Microsoft Learn / Azure / Functions / Guide for running C# Azure Functions in the isolated worker model - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide
Microsoft Learn / Azure / Functions / Azure Blob storage bindings for Azure Functions overview - Binding Types - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#binding-types
Microsoft Learn / Azure / Functions / Azure Functions binding expression patterns - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns


Thanks @Vlad for this answer. The Binder Object is a class in the in-process solution and it's part of the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs Nuget. I used it to create write/update csv files. Now with this upgrade, that functionality no longer works.
I have already injected most of the services I used but this is the one I can't seem to figure out.
static is being used because of code style of the repo I'm working on. I will also try this line services.AddSingleton<Binder>();  I used services.AddSingleton<Binder, Binder>(); and it failed when I injected it.

Just to clarify, I already have the setting you suggested and my project compiles and runs. It however fails whenever I add an unbound object to the function. So, the things that worked in in-process model no longer work in isolated-worker model.
Also, for all the classes where I added DI, I had to removed the static keyword.

@Derin, sorry, have never worked with Binder before. Please check updated answer

Thanks @Vlad, I found a workaround using BlobContainerClient. Thanks for your help.

I don't think it's a workaround. That's how it works.
